# data received through JQuery, php, mysql is not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

[image]

On entering the customer name in textbox it searches for customer info. I have generated successfully using JQuery by passing the entire table through Json variable, as I dont want any page refresh. Now I want to select the customer id generated from mysql db (php) through radio button, but the radio button event is not working. For testing purpose I have put a static table having the same radio button properties in that particular div(place for dynamic record generation using JQuery) and working fine. Hence I found that the data received through JQuery got some problem. Hope I am clear. Please find a way. Thanks in advance.

*below is the code*

**abc.php**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="full name" id="fullName" name="fullName" class="txt" style="width: 250px" />&ensp;
<input type="button" id="btSelect" value="Select" class="button-crystal" />
<div id="disp"></div>
```

**script.js**

```
$('#btSelect').click(function () {
        var form_data = {
            genCustDetails: $('#fullName').val(),
            is_ajax: 1
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "xyz.php",
            data: form_data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response)
            {
                $('#disp').html(response);
            }
        });
        return false;        
    });
```

**xyz.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['genCustDetails'])) {
    $out="";
    $result = mysql_query("select * from dbcustdetails where name like '$_POST[genCustDetails]%'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $out.='
        <table style="background-color:#eee; margin-bottom:5px;">
            <tr>
                <th class="td3">Customer ID</th>
                <td class="td4">
                    '.$row["custID"].'&ensp;<input type="radio" id="cust_ID" name="cust_ID" value="'.$row["custID"].'" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="td3">Name</th>
                <td class="td4">'.$row["name"].'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="td3">Phone No.</th>
                <td class="td4">'.$row["phno"].'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="td3">Email</th>
                <td class="td4">'.$row["email"].'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="padding:0;">
                    <b>Address</b><br/>'.$row["addr"].'
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>';       
    }
    echo json_encode($out);
}
```

Comment: you may have to bind your radio events to the ajax response using (on)[http://api.jquery.com/on/] or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe You should'nt bind the event properly for the dynamic elements in the DOM.

Try Like this

```
$('body').on('change','.radiobuttonClassorID',function(){
    //actions
});
```

Answer (score 0):

that is because your newly generated radio button is not having any event handler assigned to it.

you have to assign an event handler after the ajax call (on ajax success).
something like

```
$('input[type="radio"]').unbind('click').click(function(){
    //Your handler code
})
```